# How to execute "DELETE FROM ... WHERER .... IN VARIABLE" in PL/SQL procedure

Tags: plsql

I want to execute DELETE instruction before the end of my procedure. First I get some data in my CURSOR. On the loop of this CURSOR, for each record of my CURSOR I concatenate id values in variable named "final_list". At the end of the loop I would like to execute DELETE instruction like this : DELETE FROM my_table where my_field IN final_list. But not working.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_PURGE is
CURSOR clients IS SELECT DISTINCT client_id
                  FROM client
                  WHERE client_description LIKE 'Test%';
client clients%ROWTYPE;
id_log client.client_id%type;
final_list VARCHAR(100);

BEGIN
  final_list:='(';
  OPEN clients;
  LOOP
    FETCH clients INTO client;
    EXIT WHEN clients%notfound;   
    SELECT log_id INTO id_log
    FROM (SELECT log_id
          FROM log
          WHERE log_client_id = client.client_id
          AND client_description LIKE 'Test%'
          ORDER BY log_date DESC)
    WHERE ROWNUM < 2; 

    final_list:=concat(final_list, id_log || ',');
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE clients;
  final_list:=SUBSTR(final_list, 0, LENGTH(final_list) - 1);
  final_list:=concat(final_list, ')');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Id list: ' || final_list);
  DELETE FROM contrh_client_log WHERE contrh_client_log_id IN final_list;
  COMMIT; 
END TEST_PURGE;
```

DELETE instruction not working but no error message. When I execute the same DELETE instruction in classic SQL sheet with value of "final_list" variable, it's work.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: the best way of doing this is not by looping through a cursor, running a select statement and then a delete statement; instead, you can do it all in a single delete statement, such as:

```
DELETE FROM contrh_client_log
WHERE contrh_client_log_id IN (SELECT log_id
                               FROM   (SELECT l.log_client_id,
                                              l.log_id,
                                              row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY l.log_client_id ORDER BY log_date DESC) rn
                                       FROM   LOG l
                                              INNER JOIN client c ON l.log_client_id = c.client_id
                                       WHERE  l.client_description LIKE 'Test%'
                                       AND    c.client_description LIKE 'Test%')
                               WHERE   rn = 1);
```

(N.B. untested.)

You can then put this in a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_purge AS
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM contrh_client_log
  WHERE  contrh_client_log_id IN (SELECT log_id
                                  FROM   (SELECT l.log_client_id,
                                                 l.log_id,
                                                 row_number() over(PARTITION BY l.log_client_id ORDER BY log_date DESC) rn
                                          FROM   log l
                                          INNER  JOIN client c
                                          ON     l.log_client_id = c.client_id
                                          WHERE  l.client_description LIKE 'Test%'
                                          AND    c.client_description LIKE 'Test%')
                                  WHERE  rn = 1);

  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Doing it like this will be

- faster,
- easier to understand,
- easier to debug (you can just run the delete statement on its own outside of the procedure with little or no changes to it)
- easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: In general, when you're working with databases, you need to think set-based, not procedural, especially for things like this. It's akin to "which is faster: emptying a bath by using a spoon or a bucket? Answer: neither; it's faster to pull the plug!". The less work you do, the better (so long as it achieves your aims, of course!)